# Create rows and append them 4 elements of an object inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I have this array:

```
let filtered = 
0: {name: 'Rick Sanchez', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg'}
1: {name: 'Morty Smith', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/2.jpeg'}
2: {name: 'Summer Smith', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/3.jpeg'}
3: {name: 'Beth Smith', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/4.jpeg'}
4: {name: 'Jerry Smith', status: 'Alive', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/5.jpeg'}
5: {name: 'Abadango Cluster Princess', status: 'Alive', species: 'Alien', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/6.jpeg'}
6: {name: 'Abradolf Lincler', status: 'unknown', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/7.jpeg'}
7: {name: 'Adjudicator Rick', status: 'Dead', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/8.jpeg'}
8: {name: 'Agency Director', status: 'Dead', species: 'Human', image: 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/9.jpeg'}
```

I have more elements inside the array, but I want to put the info in cards (I'm using bootsrap 5 btw) but each 4 cards have to be inside a row and then I have to create a new row to put append them the next 4 cards

With map I can load the characters card but, how to append then each 4 cards in a new row??
Basically the structure should be

```
div.row
  div.col
  div.col
  div.col
  div.col
div.row
  div.col
  div.col
  div.col
  div.col
```

Should I use a for loop?? It could work but I'm not sure if it is the best solution, with .map I have no idea how to properly make a row each 4 elements

Im using only vanilla js

**Edit:**
I'm working in a website to load the characthers of rick and morty in cards with a click button

Initially my code was:

```
const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";
const button = document.querySelector("#button-app")
const app = document.querySelector("#app") 

async function execute() {
  await createRow()
  await fetchAPI()
}

async function createRow(){
  const newRow = document.createElement("div");
  newRow.classList = "row"
  console.log("add")
  app.appendChild(newRow)
}

button.addEventListener("click", execute, false)

async function fetchAPI() {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const results = await response.json()
  const data = results.results


  data.map((result) => {
    const col = document.createElement("div")
    col.classList= "col-12 col-sm-4 col-lg-3"
    col.id = "col"
    col.innerHTML = characters(result)
    app.appendChild(col) 
    console.log(index) 
  })
}
function characters(character) {
  return`
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="${character.image}" alt="">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">${character.name}</h5>
      <span class="badge bg-success">${character.status}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
}
```

it worked to laod the cards but, I didnt have the idea yet to load the rows, so I decided to recreate the code
const url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character";
const app = document.querySelector("#app")

```
async function fetchAPI() {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const results = await response.json()
  const data = results.results
  //data is an array
  const info = data.map(({name, status, image})=> (name, status, image))
  //map transform, filteredData contains the filteredArray
  let filteredData = data.map(({name, status, species, image}) => ({name,status,species, image}))
  console.log(filteredData)
}
//bring the data
async function createCards() {
  filteredData.map(result, index) => {
    if (index = 0 || (index + 1) % 4 === 0){
      const newRow = document.createElement("div");
      newRow.classList = "row"
      app.appendChild(newRow)
    }
  }
}
```

(app is a div with the class container where the js will work)
I'm thinking that now working with newRow I could load and append there the cards, but... Im not sure if is still the best solution

Comment: Does it have to be an actual row or look like a new row? can you just use class `col-3` for `div.col` (or add line break `<div class="w-100"></div>` in row...add `</div><div class="row">` if `i%4==0`?)?

Comment: can you share the js code you do have that is relevant to the question (current map)?

Comment: @depperm already share my js